# Are there 32- and 64-bit versions of Microsoft.Sharepoint.dll?

Tags: windows, sharepoint, 32bit-64bit

Does Microsoft.Sharepoint.dll come in both 32bit and 64bit flavors?

So if I develop on a 64bit machine. Do you think if I install MOSS 32bit, I will be able to deploy successfully to a 32bit server. Or can I just copy the 32bit DLL's inplace of my 64bit DLLs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/970359

Answer (score 0):

Yes but be careful when writing code and referencing the dll from two different machines.  You may be dealing with version differences for instance writing code against MOSS 2007 and using that dll will not work when porting that over to MOSS 2003.

Comment: Do you really mean MOSS 2003 here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a 64 bit version of that dll to build against - you can download from here:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=0A50DA0F-7C94-4814-BBFE-2B66FE4A9087&displaylang=en